# PGP Decrypt using ANT

Tags: encryption, ant, pgp

We have an ant build file that needs to encrypt/decrypt a bunch of files using a PGP Public Key.
Is there a native (or library) ant task to do so. I really would like to avoid solutions that involve the use of `<exec>` (unless ther is no other way around).

Much obliged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you do it with `<exec>`:

```
<exec executable="sh" >
    <arg value="-c" />
    <arg value="echo ${encrypted.passphrase} | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --output ${data.dir}/Performance.dat --decrypt ${data.dir.encrypted}/${encrypted.file.name}"/>
</exec>
```

This way you provide the key passphrase in one line. But it would be nice to do it using something that is no OS dependent.

Comment: You can specify the OS in the executable command, so you can have a different executable for each OS. The other is to use custom made Ant tasks (either third party or home grown) and use <taskdef>. The latter is more difficult, and I usually prefer the jars that contain these tasks to be part of the project, so a user doesn't have to download and install the jars in their Antlib themselves.

Comment: @David W - I have found some OpenPGP related libs for ANT but all of them are made for signing and I'm trying to Encrypt/Decrypt, do you happen to know some lib that can actually do that?

Comment: I've never seen ant tasks for encrypting and decrypting. We had to do something similar once, but simply used the <exec> task and had one for Windowa and one for Unix.

Comment: @David W -I was afraid you'd say that. Aparently there isn't any at all. So the only way is with <exec> =S

Comment: That's not really so bad. Many of the optional Ant tasks I've seen simply do an exec call to the command line utility anyway. And, that even includes utilities that do have a real API. Just specif the OS in the Exec, and you might need two <exec> tasks (one for Unix/Linux/Mac and one for Windows).